# Increase Stroke Weight By Percentage

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, scale

I know how to increase the stroke weight in Illustrator, but I have custom stroke weight points on an object and I'd like to make the whole object's stroke thicker without losing the customized weight points.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the stroke weight.

Custom width points *scale* when the weight of the stroke changes.

If you mean you want width points to remain constant while increasing the stroke weight - that's illogical and not possible since width points *are* the determining factor of the stroke weight when used. If you want to *only* adjust *part* of the stroke to change weight, you need to adjust width markers, not the overall stroke weight.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Illustrator > Preferences > General and check Scale & Stroke Effects, it will scale the strokes with the rest of the object